# Case of the adjective in "made someone more something"

Tags: grammar-choice, sentence-translation, english-to-latin-translation

In *A new latin composition* by Charles E. Bennett one may find following statement to translate into latin (from Lesson IV):

*This circumstance made the troops more courageous.*

My attempt at translation is:

> Res haec milites fortioribus egit.

I used *fortior* in ablative, however I don't know whether it is correct.

This leads to the more general question: what should be the case of the adjective Z in "X made Y (more) Z" construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use *facere* and accusative instead of *agere* and ablative:

> *Res haec milites fortiores fecit.*

However, a literal translation of "to make something something" is not the only option.
I would phrase the cause as a causal ablative.
(Note that it is the cause, not the outcome, that is in ablative in this approach.)
For circumstances I suggest *rerum condicio*, but there are other options.
My offer for a translation is:

> This circumstance made the troops more courageous.
>   *Milites rerum condicione fortiores erant.*
>   (lit. "The soldiers were more courageous due to the circumstances.")

Many choices are a matter of style.
The most important correction to your attempt is a grammatical one: *fortiores* should not be in ablative.
If you make something something directly, both somethings are in accusative.
In passive they are both in nominative (*milites fortiores facti sunt*).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
*If you make something something directly, both somethings are in accusative. In passive they are both in nominative (milites fortiores facti sunt).* This is quite strange for me - it's good to know.

Comment: @PrzemysławP I'm glad to be able to help! Judging by your Polish-sounding name and what little I remember of Russian, I suspect your surprise is due to Slavic influence. Latin seems to be more fond of double accusatives than Slavic languages.

Comment: Indeed, in Polish it would be a strange and wrong sentence with double accusative.